# @ symbol causing error with regex when using regex in javascript to validate email address

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to use javascript and regex to validate emails in my MVC view page.

I have the following javascript function:

```
function (input) {
    if (input.attr('name') === "user_name" && input.val() != "") {
        var pattern = "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
        return !!input.val().match(pattern);
    }
}
```

I'm using the same sort of function with another regex pattern and that one works but this one seems to be having an issue with the @ symbol. with the current pattern I keep getting the error:

"\" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

I have tried updating the regex to have the part after the @ symbol surrounded by brackets but it still doesnt work. Any ideas how I can get this regex to work to validate emails?

Comment: The pattern should be delimited by `/` not `"`. Use `/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/`. Also, change `.match` to `.test` and remove a `!`.

Comment: You need to escape the `@` in Razor by using a double `@@`.

Comment: Try one of these ways to instantiate a regex `regex = new RegExp("\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*");`

or  

`regex = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;`

Comment: DavidG was correct, I added the double @@ and it works

Comment: Why are you doing this when there is already a built in `[EmailAddress]` validation attribute that gives both client side and (more importantly) server side validation out of the box

Comment: @StephenMuecke I believe [EmailAddress] will allow multiple periods in a row, which isnt allowed in a valid email

Comment: You can see the regex that is use in the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/EmailAddressAttribute.cs). If you do not want that, then create you own `[RegularExpression]` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that makes sense, thanks! I'm going to try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post the answer so I can mark my question answered. The issue was that I needed to escape the @ in Razor with double @@.